# I have to check if the string contains: alphanumeric, alphabetical , digits, lowercase and uppercase characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
def fun(s):
    for i in s:
        if i.isalnum():
            print("True")
        if i.isalpha():
            print("True")
        if i.isdigit():
            print("True")
        if i.isupper():
            print("True") 
        if i.islower():
            print("True")
s=input().split()
fun(s)
```

why it prints true only once even though it is in a for loop

Comment: What is the input? Are you giving only one word are input? Try printing `s` after you take input

Comment: A good tool to test unexpected program behaviour of small functions is [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check if the whole string contains those different characters types then you don't actually have to loop through the string. You just can use the any keyword.

```
def fun(s):
    if any(letter.isalnum() for letter in s):
        print("Is alphanumeric")
    if any(letter.isalpha() for letter in s):
        print("Is alpha")
    if any(letter.isdigit() for letter in s):
        print("Is digit")
    if any(letter.isupper() for letter in s):
        print("Is upper")
    if any(letter.islower() for letter in s):
        print("Is lower")

s=str(input())
fun(s)
```

Comment: thanks mate !! but I am having a problem when I pass s= integer value as it gives a runtime error. what should I do so that it takes both int and string and works normally for them

Comment: I've edited it now. All was needed is to cast the input value as a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
string = input()

print (any(c.isalnum() for c in s))
print (any(c.isalpha() for c in s))
print (any(c.isdigit() for c in s))
print (any(c.islower() for c in s))
print (any(c.isupper() for c in s))
```

Comment: Python has a built in print(any()) function for it that returns True or False for the given case

Answer (score 2):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    print(any(c.isalnum()  for c in s))
    print(any(c.isalpha() for c in s))
    print(any(c.isdigit() for c in s))
    print(any(c.islower() for c in s))
    print(any(c.isupper() for c in s))
```

## code is updated for python 3 using any function without uing if else

Answer (score 0):

You are applying string methods to **entire words** rather than to individual characters. You are not applying an `any` or `all` condition to check whether *any* or *all* of the characters in each word fulfill each criterion.

For example, with an `any` condition for each word:

```
def fun(s):
    for i in s:
        print('\n', i)
        if any(letter.isalnum() for letter in i):
            print('Alnum', True)
        if any(letter.isalpha() for letter in i):
            print('Alpha', True)
        if any(letter.isdigit() for letter in i):
            print('Digit', True)
        if any(letter.isupper() for letter in i):
            print('Upper', True) 
        if any(letter.islower() for letter in i):
            print('Lower', True)

s = input().split()
fun(s)
```

Example result:

```
One test 123

 One
Alnum True
Alpha True
Upper True
Lower True

 test
Alnum True
Alpha True
Lower True

 123
Alnum True
Digit True
```

Comment: but if I apply to each individual character ,then alnum will never be true as it must have a numeric as well as alphabet . If I check for each character ,most of them would return false. I thought I can check out the words individually(like one or test ) for each condition and not for each character like ['o','n','e']. suggestions are welcome . also tell me what I am not able to understand here

Comment: @palak, You should define [in your question, not as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51320667/edit) precisely what you are looking to achieve. Right now, it's not clear. I've supplied one interpretation which is `any` for each word.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    print (any([c.isalnum() for c in s]))
    print (any([c.isalpha() for c in s]))
    print (any([c.isdigit() for c in s]))
    print (any([c.islower() for c in s]))
    print (any([c.isupper() for c in s]))
```

Comment: This code only answer doesn't appear to answer the question of why true is only printed once, though it does show an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    print (any([c.isalnum() for c in s]))
    print (any([c.isalpha() for c in s]))
    print (any([c.isdigit() for c in s]))
    print (any([c.islower() for c in s]))
    print (any([c.isupper() for c in s]))
```

Use of the any keyword, checks all the letters of the alphabet and returns true I any one of the letter satisfies it.

Answer (score 0):

The any() function is an inbuilt function in Python which returns true
if any of the elements of a given iterable
( List, Dictionary, Tuple, set, etc) are True else it returns False.

```
if len(s) > 0 and len(s) < 1000:
    print(any([i.isalnum() for i in s]))
    print(any([i.isalpha() for i in s]))
    print(any([i.isdigit() for i in s]))
    print(any([i.islower() for i in s]))
    print(any([i.isupper() for i in s]))
```

Answer (score 0):

here  i built a function to use it instead of repeating, but the problem is how to call a built-in python method. this why i use getattr() function to read my function arguments as i want

```
def test(str_1, fun):
    for i in range(len(str_1)):
        if getattr(str_1[i], fun)():
            return True
    return False
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = raw_input()
    methods = ["isalnum", "isalpha", "isdigit", "islower", "isupper"]
    for method in methods:
        print(test(s, method))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying string methods to entire words rather than to individual characters.
By applying string methods check each character and then update the return value will have most efficient time complexity.

```
def main():
    S = input()
    a1,a2,a3,a4,a5=False,False,False,False,False
    
    for s in S:
        a1 = a1 or s.isalnum()
        a2 = a2 or s.isalpha()
        a3 = a3 or s.isdigit()
        a4 = a4 or s.islower()
        a5 = a5 or s.isupper()
       
    print(a1)
    print(a2)
    print(a3)
    print(a4)
    print(a5) 
    
    return 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    a1,a2,a3,a4,a5=False,False,False,False,False
  
    for i in s:
        a1=True if i.isalnum()==True else a1
        a2=True if i.isalpha()==True else a2
        a3=True if i.isdigit()==True else a3
        a4=True if i.islower()==True else a4
        a5=True if i.isupper()==True else a5
    
    print(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,sep="\n")
```